# Spring Batch: Reading a File : if field is empty setting the default value

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

> I am very new to spring batch. I have requirement in which i have to read a file having a header(Field Names) record and data records
>
> 1. i have to validate 1st record (check the field names matching against set of predefined names)- note that this record need to be skipped- i mean should not be part of items in processor)
> 2. read and store rest of the field values to a POJO
> 3. if the field 'date' is empty , i need to set the default value as 'xxxx-yy-zz'
>
> i am unable to 1st and 3rd requirement with batch
> here is the sample reader XML. please help

```
 <bean id="reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
     <property name="resource" value="classpath:input/import" /> 
     <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper" ref="line.mapper"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="line.mapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping .DefaultLineMapper">
    <property name="lineTokenizer" ref="line.tokenizer"/>
    <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="fieldSet.enity.mapper"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="line.tokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transfo  rm.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
     <property name="delimiter">
       <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transfo rm.DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB"/>
     </property>
     <property name="names" value="id,date,age " />
     <property name="strict" value="false"/>
</bean>

  <bean id="fieldSet.enity.mapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping .BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
      <property name="targetType" value="a.b.myPOJO"/>
      <property name="customEditors">
           <map>
              <entry key="java.util.Date">
                     <bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.C ustomDateEditor">
                           <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                                         <constructor-arg value="yyyy-mm-dd" />
                                 </bean>
                           </constructor-arg>
                           <constructor-arg value="true" />
                     </bean>
               </entry>
          </map>
     </property>
```

Comment: What should happen if validation fails on the first line? Completely skip the file?

Answer (score 2):

Create your own custom FieldSetMapper like below

```
CustomeFieldSetMapper implements FieldSetMapper<a.b.myPOJO> {

@Override
public a.b.myPOJO mapFieldSet(FieldSet fs) {
           a.b.myPOJO  myPOJO = new a.b.myPOJO();
           if(fs.readString("date").isEmpty()){
               myPOJO.setDate("xxxx-yy-zz");
           }
           return a.b.myPOJO;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You think you should do date set in `ItemProcessor`.

Also, if `<property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />` not fill your requirements - extend `FlatFileItemReader` and validate first line manually in it.

Comment: I am planning to use another reader which will read the header and validates format and quit. thats why i have given <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" /> for this reader. if thats not a correct approach,  then your are right. i should not skip he 1st line

Comment: for setting the date can i do something like this<bean class="org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor">
                        <constructor-arg>
                            <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                                <constructor-arg value="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
                            </bean>
                        </constructor-arg>
                        <constructor-arg value="true"/>
                        <property name="value" value="0000-00-00"/> 
                    </bean>

Comment: Don't get your last comment

Comment: I wanted to set the value for date field if that is blank. So can i use CustomEditors to do that by adding a property like as shown below?<property name="value" value="0000-00-00"/> will it be set as a default value?

Comment: Just implement your own `ItemProcessor` and modify your object as you want

Comment: It will break the rule of separation of concerns.ie, if i have a validation/formatting step, i can skip validation just by commenting few lines in job-context xml.

Comment: Create your own custom FieldSetMapper like below